# Specifying a default export format for the CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make PDF the default export option for a Crystal Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076070/how-do-i-make-pdf-the-default-export-option-for-a-crystal-report)

There appears to have been a change in behaviour between versions of the viewer that have changed the default from PDF to the virtually useless (in our scenario) native Crystal Reports format.

Is it possible to specify the default file type to use when the end user clicks the export button in the winforms [CrystalReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227057%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Not that I know of...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076070/how-do-i-make-pdf-the-default-export-option-for-a-crystal-report/1076314#1076314

Comment: @dotjoe Hadn't seen that duplicate - shame I can't accept the answer over there to replace the existing button with one of my own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

I solved it by disabling the Export button and creating a menu option "Export to PDF" that calls one of the Export methods of the Report object.